# Java, How does the compiler know which constructor to call in this lambda expression

Tags: java

I have a question, I'm learning java with a Book, and as I've copied some code in there (and made some changes) and made some investigations, I noticed something odd..., here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, (event) ->
    {
        System.out.println("At the Tone, the time is" + Instant.ofEpochMilli(event.getWhen()));
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    });

    timer.start();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quit?");
    System.exit(0);

}
```

It's just a code that notifies you if a second passes. (this code compiles and runs smoothly)

as you can see Timer Constructor requires 2 pars (int, ActionListener)

```
public Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener)
```

and the ActionListener Interface has one method that is actionPerformed and requires ActionEvent parameter

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);
```

Now here is my question, when calling this actionPerformed Method in that lambda expression above
How does the compiler know which constructor to call to instantiate ActionEvent without feeding him any clues about the parameters, ActionEvent has no "No argument Constructor" and the method getWhen() is not static (obj must be instantiated)

Here are all the constructors of ActionEvent:

```
public ActionEvent(Object source, int id, String command)

public ActionEvent(Object source, int id, String command, int modifiers)

public ActionEvent(Object source, int id, String command, long when,
                   int modifiers)
```

I really hope I made myself clear!, Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The compiler does not know! ;-)
It is the `Timer` instance that will create the `ActionEvent` instance at runtime every `delay` and the `Timer` instance will call the `ActionListener` method `actionPerformed` with the `ActionEvent` it created.

You can have a look at one of the implementation here:
http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/Timer-source.html

```
/**
 * Fire the action event, named "Timer" and having the numeric
 * identifier, equal to the numer of events that have been
 * already fired before.
 */
void fireActionPerformed()
{
  fireActionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, ticks++, "Timer"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!, but when the Timer instance create the ActionEvent instance, what constructor does it call exactly? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the source code of `javax.swing.Timer`, we note that all the ActionListeners of the `Timer` are stored on a `javax.swing.event.EventListenerList`, called `listenerList`. 
They are called in this line(s):

```java
fireActionPerformed(new ActionEvent(Timer.this, 0, getActionCommand(),
                                                    System.currentTimeMillis(),
                                                    0));
```

With fireActionPerformed:

```java
protected void fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Guaranteed to return a non-null array
        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();

        // Process the listeners last to first, notifying
        // those that are interested in this event
        for (int i=listeners.length-2; i>=0; i-=2) {
            if (listeners[i]==ActionListener.class) {
                ((ActionListener)listeners[i+1]).actionPerformed(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

The regular constructor selection process applies.

Answer (score 2):

The `Timer` constructor just receives a listener and registers it in its listeners list. When the timer ticks (where listener should be called), the `Timer` instance creates a new ActionEvent (See `Timer.java:245`) and passes it over to the registered listeners.

So simply saying, the compiler doesn't create it for you. Instead `Timer` class does.